# How can a git-submodule be published and cloned?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, git-clone

I created a git repository, where I store everything for a project. The project is private, but part of it will be published. Therefore, I created a submodule inside the repo, that I want to publish exclusively. This brought up certain questions:

1. Can a submodule be exclusively cloned and published? If yes, how? If not, what would be the alternative?
2. Where can I find the URL online on Gitlab for the submodule (not the complete repo)?

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: A submodule *is* a repository, and in general, has no idea that it's a submodule. So just send the submodule repository off as a regular public repository and you're done.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269285/publish-modules-from-a-java-project-on-github-and-integrate-into-intellij). Please check the solution on the post. Could be helpful.